# Save SqlLite Database to local strage

Tags: android, sqlite

I Have a ToDo App in which I am using the SqlLite database, I want to create and save a .db file of my SqlLite databse in my internal storage by creating a folder of my app name.
I am not sure How to do that.
Thanx.

Comment: Have you researched/attempted any of this that we can help you with?

Answer (score 0):

You have to

1. Ensure that the database is in a state that is sound.

- If using WAL the default logging mode from Android 9+ then this requires that the database is fully committed. If using Journal mode this doesn't matter. See :-

  - https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/compatibility-wal
  - https://sqlite.org/wal.html

2. Ascertain the file's path, if using the default location then using the Context's `getDatabasePath(<database_name>)` method will return the file from which you can get the path using the File's `getAbsolutePath()` (or the `getCanonicalPath()` method. See -

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)
- https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File

3. Create the directory/folder, using the File's `mkDir` or `mkDirs` method, where the data is to be stored.
4. Copy the File to the storage location path.

- see https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/

This is an extract from code used for backing up a database (that will commit (checkpoint) if the database uses WAL) :-

```
            String dbfilename = context.getDatabasePath(<the database name>).getPath();
            try {
                checkpointIfWALEnabled(context);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbfile);
                OutputStream backup = new FileOutputStream(<path to storage location (assumes directories exist)>);
                
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
                int length;
                while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    backup.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                backup.flush();
                backup.close();
                fis.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

- note that `<the database name>` and `<path to storage location (assumes directories exist)>` have to be changed accordingly.

With:-

```
private void checkpointIfWALEnabled(Context context) {
    Cursor csr;
    int wal_busy = -99, wal_log = -99, wal_checkpointed = -99;
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(<the database name>).getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode", null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        String mode = csr.getString(0);
        if (mode.toLowerCase().equals("wal")) {
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint", null);
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                wal_busy = csr.getInt(0);
                wal_log = csr.getInt(1);
                wal_checkpointed = csr.getInt(2);
            }
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)", null);
            csr.getCount();
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint", null);
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                wal_busy = csr.getInt(0);
                wal_log = csr.getInt(1);
                wal_checkpointed = csr.getInt(2);
            }
    }
    csr.close();
    db.close(); // Should checkpoint the database anyway.
}
```